# Cancelled Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I send an email through a guided send and arrived this morning to find out that it has been cancelled under tracking. Does someone have to do this manually or can this occur because of a system failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can automatically happen if there is an error in the email. For example if you have ampscript that only runs at send time and the syntax is incorrect.

You have a couple ways to debug this:

1. Easiest way is to talk to support as they will have the error log - but this also can take at least a couple hours to get the log.
2. Remove all Send Time only conditionals and do a send preview - to see where the error is occurring
3. Check for any exclusion scripts or outside scripting that can be affecting this send and verify that it is correctly syntaxed and does not throw errors.